# Counting words in assembly x86 without standard library

Tags: assembly, x86

I was trying to write simple code in x86 assembly that counts number of words in a string but without using standard library (with `-nostdlib` option in GCC). For example if a string looks like that: `aaa ab   cccc c`
my program should write `4` as an output. This means that checking if a next character is space is not enough but I have no idea how else should I approach to this task. Could you help me with it?

Nevertheless, I was trying to check those spaces. I wrote my code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.globl _start

//preparing esi register to store the string and
//edi register to store number of spaces
_start:
  xor esi, esi
  xor edi, edi
  mov esi, offset msg

//First I check if I reach the end of a string - if so I go to an end
//then I compare character with space ASCII number
check:
  mov eax, [esi]
  cmp eax, offset len
  je end
  cmp eax, ' '
  je adding
  inc esi
  jmp check

adding:
  inc edi
  inc esi
  jmp check

//finally, I just write the number of spaces on screen
end:
  mov eax, sys_write
  mov ebx, stdout
  mov ecx, edi
  mov edx, 1
  int 0x80

  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 0x80

.data
  .equ sys_read, 3
  .equ sys_write, 4
  .equ stdin, 0
  .equ stdout, 1

msg:
  .ascii "aaa bbb cc    ddd"
  .equ len, $-msg
```

But program is still giving me "core dumped" error and I have no idea why is that. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Does `jmp _start` seem like a good idea to you? Did you read the manpages for `read()` and `write()`? Including the part where you are supposed to pass a pointer to a valid address?

Comment: I didn't notice this, thank you. But even after fixing this up, the problem still occurs.

Comment: You should *really* have another look at your syscall-code. It's so broken it's not even comprehensible any more. Are you trying to call both `read()` and `write()` simultaneously or could you just not decide which you liked better?

Comment: I fixed some problems I found, but there is still something else. If it comes to writing the number on screen. I first pass 4 to eax (sys_write), then 1 to ebx (standard output) and number in edi to ecx register. Finally I pass 1 to edx as I want to write only one byte (one number). And then I'm ending the work of a program by passing 1 to eax (sys_exit) and 0 as an error code. Is that right?

Comment: The `.equ` only assigns a value to a symbol. It doesn't define a value in memory. See the documentation for the [`equ` directive](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_7.html#SEC84). So, `.equ len, $-msg` assigns the value of `$-msg` to the symbol `len`, but the value of `$-msg` does not appear in memory after your `msg` string. So your `mov eax, [esi]` followed by `cmp esi, offset len` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It's very emberrasing mistype I made when I was writing this post. I'm really sorry about that. It should compare ``eax`` with ``offset len``. Unfortunately, it still doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: You should seriously consider commenting your code.  I don't mean one comment per 15 lines, either.  You are clearly very new at assembly, so commenting each line is not a bad idea (nor is it uncommon).

Comment: Comparing `eax` with `offset len` has the same problem for reasons I described in my prior comment. The prior `mov eax, [esi]` moves a character to `eax`. Why would the value of the character have any relation to the length? The fact that you're using `offset len` seems to imply that you are treating the symbol `len` as if it's an address of something, but it isn't. It's a symbolically defined, assembly-time constant. The code still seems to assume that the `.equ` sets memory to the values of the `.equ`, but it doesn't. The values are only known by the assembler at assembly time.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I am commenting my code but it is detailed and in my mother tongue. To quickly describe what I mean, I used much more overall commentary because I was assuming that everyone here will know the basics. @lurker Thank you for detailed explanation. I think I now understand what you was trying to tell me. Now it's stupid but with ``offset len`` I was trying to determine end of a string because I'm assuming that this is not a Null-terminated string. But know I have no clue how to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned about a debug option which really help me understand what I've done wrong. With a little of external help, I did this task. It is not the best looking code I ever encountered but it works.

I want to thank everyone for help, I really appreciate it. I'm also sorry for all mistakes I made when creating this question. I'll try not do the same mistakes twice.

Here is my solution (I changed it a little. Now the user types a string to program):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.globl _start

_start:
  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, offset msg
  mov edx, 100                # maximum number of characters
  int 0x80

  xor ebx, ebx                # counter of words

_loop:
  mov al, [ecx]               
  cmp al, 10                  # 10 is the end of a string
  je intToString
  cmp al, ' '                 
  jne word                    # if it's not a space, it's a beginning of the word
  inc ecx
  jmp _loop

word:
  inc ecx
  mov al, [ecx]
  cmp al, 10                  
  je wordadd                  # case when string ends with space
  cmp al, ' '                 
  jne word                   # if the next characters is a space, it means that it's the end of a word
  inc ecx
  inc ebx                     
  jmp _loop

intToString10:                # changing the counter int to string (case when it's bigger than 10)
  mov eax, ecx                # By dividing number by 10 I split the number (the result is quotient and remainder)
  mov dl, 10                  # which I then put in the right order to buffer
  div dl
  add al, '0'                 # changing number to string by adding a 0 at the end
  mov edx, offset buffer       
  mov [edx], al               
  add ah, '0'                 
  inc edx
  mov [edx], ah
  jmp end

wordadd:                     # case when the whole string ends with space
  inc ebx                     

intToString:                 # changing int to string (case when it's smaller than 10)
  mov ecx, ebx
  cmp ecx, 10                 
  jae intToString10
  add ecx, '0'                
  mov [buffer], ecx            

end:
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, offset buffer
  mov edx, 5                  
  int 0x80

mov eax, 1                  
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80

.data

buffer:
  .ascii "    \n"            

msg:
  .skip 100
```

Comment: Seems subroutine "slowo" is not defined. Please check

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I edited my answer. "słowo" means "word" in Polish. I just didn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if you specified it or not, but you can just link the C standard library to your application and call strtok() and count the total number of non-NULL pointers it returns in a loop.

```
p = strtok(str,delimeters);
while (p != null) {
    words++; p = strtok(NULL,delimeters);
}

mov  words, 0
push delimeters
push str
call strtok
add  esp, 8
cmp  eax, 0
je   done

doAgain:
inc  words
push delimeters
push 0
call strtok
add  esp, 8
cmp  eax, 0
jne  doAgain

done:
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and for your effort. Unfortunately, I did specify that I don't want to use a standard library.